# How can I stop Edge(browser) stretching my images?

Tags: html, css

I have a picture tag looking like this

```css
.flexD {
  display: flex;
  margin: 0 auto;
  width: 90%;
}

.flexP {
  display: flex;
}

.imgInP {
  margin: auto 0;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
  <title></title>
</head>

<body>
  <div class="flexD">
    <picture class="flexP">
      <!-- I do have some source tags-->
      <img src="http://placehold.it/100x80"> </picture>
    <p> content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content</p>
  </div>
 <!-- I am using this code--> 
    <div class="flexD">
    <picture class="flexP">
      <!-- I do have some source tags-->
      <img class = "imgInP" src="http://placehold.it/100x80"> </picture>
    <p> content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content</p>
  </div>

</body>

</html>
```

On Chrome, the code works and looks like the picture below, but on Edge my picture is stretched like the above. Does this mean that my margin: auto 0;  is not working on Edge? How can I fix this?

Comment: Would you mind sharing the picture of edge and chrome so that we can see the differences?

Answer (score 0):

If my understanding is correct on your requirement check this out:

if you think the `image` is getting stretched then you can use same image as `content:url` and assign `height` and `width` so that it will remain consistent across browsers.

```css
.flexD {
  display: flex;
  margin: 0 auto;
  width: 90%;
}

.flexP {
  display: flex;
}

.imgInP {
  content: url(http://placekitten.com/301/301);
  width: 100px;
  height: 80px;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div class="flexD">
    <picture class="flexP">
      <!-- I do have some source tags-->
      <img class="imgInP">
    </picture>
    <p> content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content</p>
  </div>
  <!-- I am using this code-->
  <div class="flexD">
    <picture class="flexP">
      <!-- I do have some source tags-->
      <img class="imgInP"> </picture>
    <p> content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content</p>
  </div>

</body>
```

Answer (score -1):

You can use object-fit property of css, it stops images to be stretched.

```
.imgInP{
       object-fit: cover;
 }
```